# Magento Module is loading too much time in custom module at admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have create a custom module at admin ,in my local machine it is working fine but at server it is not loading and even not showing header and footer as well,It is only showing logo and logged user,

Cannot debug how to resolve this issue.
My machine and server configuration is same,Please advice me for resolving this.I am using Magento 1.8 .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comment from [magento-root]/index.php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Also enable logs(Admin> System> Developer> Log Settings) and check the error in [root]/var/log

Comment: I already use this,nginx is showing memory exhausted for this module,so i had increase memory but after 4-5 days again got this issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to:

- Clear your cache
- Create the corresponding module configuration file in app/etc/modules/*Your_Extension*.xml